# using openURL to jump to Baidu Map app from within an ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am using the following API :

> [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: options:
> completionHandler: ];

The argument to openURL is generated by the following example format string :

> @"baidumap://map/direction?origin=latlng:%f,%f |
> name:我的位置&destination=latlng:%f,%f|name:终点&mode=driving"

The app runs smoothly during runtime but fails to invoke baidumap.

Have attached an anonymous fuction to completionHandler :

> ^(BOOL success)
> {
> if (success)
> NSLog(@"Invoke success = 1");
> else
> NSLog(@"Invoke success = 0");
> }

The augument passes in via "BOOL sucess" is always 0.

I suspect that the problem comes from the format string.

Hope that somebody who is familiar with Baidu map API can give me some help.

Comment: How did you get that URL? I guess there are invalid URL characters, like spaces, etc that might need percent escaping...

Comment: "stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding" is depeicated according to xcode so I changed it to "stringByRemovingPercentEncoding" as suggusted by written material ...

Comment: But after I changed back as suggested by you and Ptit Xav, it works ... many thanks.

Comment: The URL was modelled after an example on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated on the baidumap site you need some escaping :

```
NSString *urlString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"baidumap://map/direction?origin=latlng:%f,%f|name:我的位置&destination=latlng:%f,%f|name:终点&mode=driving",currentLatitude, currentLongitude,_shopLat,_shopLon] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
```

And also to give geographic coordinates for sources and destination